# What is the state of the art in computerised coding of Thematic Apperception Tests (TATs)?

Tags: measurement, test, experimental-psychology, software

[Thematic Apperception Tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thematic_Apperception_Test) (TATs) involve showing test takers pictures and getting them to write stories based on the pictures. Coding such stories for themes and traits can be complex, time-consuming, and potentially suffer from issues of unreliability. Thus, it would be interesting to see whether automated computerised coding could make the process of scoring TATs more efficient, reliable, and valid.

- **What is the current state of computerised coding of TATs?**
- **How does the reliability and validity of computerised coding compare to human coding?**

Comment: I've looked into this a number of times since first coming across this question, but I have difficulty imagining how a computerized TAT would work, and there doesn't seem to be any literature on computerized TATs at all. Do they exist? It would be helpful to have a starting point.

Comment: @ChristianHummeluhr I haven't looked into it myself. Many years back, I helped out coding a whole pile of responses to TATs. It was quite resource intensive. You also have all sorts of challenges with inter-rater reliability, and so forth. So I was curious whether anyone has looked into computerised scoring.

Answer (score 3):

The state of the art in computer-scored Thematic Apperception Tests (TAT) as of 2015 appears to be that **computer-scored TATs do not exist**.

There does not appear to be any relevant results on Google Scholar, Web of Science or Scopus for any search I can think of including the term "thematic apperception" which yield any example or mention of computer-scored TATs, and all recent studies utilizing TATs have reported using standard versions (e.g., Turk et al., 2010). A 2013 book dedicated to the TAT, *[A practical guide to the Thematic Apperception Test: The TAT in clinical practice](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=MkCw8sTjTj0C&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=%22thematic%20apperception%22&ots=IKQrMcHOxJ&sig=vDziIJmDy9AU19lYqzNeYlYTj2A#v=onepage&q=%22thematic%20apperception%22&f=false)* also fails to make any mention of computer-scored or otherwise computerized implementations of the TAT.

## References

- Aronow, E., Weiss, K. A., & Reznikoff, M. (2013). A practical guide to the Thematic Apperception Test: The TAT in clinical practice. Routledge.
- Turk, A. A., Brown, W. S., Symington, M., & Paul, L. K. (2010). Social narratives in agenesis of the corpus callosum: linguistic analysis of the Thematic Apperception Test. Neuropsychologia, 48(1), 43-50.